# Booting a linux kernel in Oneplus3 device

Tags: linux, boot, arm64

Bootloader of my op3 device is unlocked.
I am trying to install linux-5.3 to be run on Oneplus3. Yes, I only want the kernel to load. That's it!. I don't even want to care about the init process after kernel loading.

Before I started I tried compiling the same version of the kernel for `x86_64` architecture. It produced a `bzImage` which I renamed to `vmlinuz-linux` and copied to `/boot` folder. I restarted the computer and syslinux loaded my vmlinuz-linux and displayed the message

> Remove disk and press any key to reboot...

A message from vmlinuz-linux proving that it has been loaded.

I am trying to the same with my oneplus3 device,
I used the defconfigs from this [repo](https://github.com/android-linux-stable/op3). I basically copied `<oneplus3_kernel_repo>/boot/arch/arm64/configs/` to `linux-5.3/boot/arch/arm64/configs` and started compiling using the commands

```
cd linux-5.3
#configuration
make -j16 ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- defconfig
#build
make -j16 ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
```

This process gave me `Image` and `Image.gz` in the folder `<linux-5.3>/arch/arm64/boot/` which I suppose is the kernel.

Now. Where do I put this kernel file in my oneplus3 so the oneplus3 bootloader picks it up?

Also if my compilation process is not right, kindly point it out...

Comment: Excellent question. Per the help center, "The underlying *nix OS on an embedded system or handheld device (e.g. an Android phone)"; I believe this is the correct place for your question. Are you using the stock bootloader?

Comment: AFAIK bootloader resides in ROM in android devices. I think I am using the stock bootloader.